# Difference in functionality between simulator and real device

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

so I'm currently building a Flutter App and was able to test it through Apples TestFlight. The problem I'm facing is the following: on a page where users are able to create a post ("new event") a couple of things need to be filled. Here you can see how it should look (screenshot from the simulator):

[image]

And this is how it looks in the Beta version on a real device:

[image]

Does anyone has a clue on why this is not working properly?

Thanks.

I changed the line "expands: true" to "expands: false", because I thought the Textfield expands to the rest of the page.

```
TextField(
                                  controller: _descriptionController,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                  maxLines: null,
                                  expands: false,
                                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                                  onChanged: (value) {},
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    hintText: 'Describe the event...',
                                      ),
                                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to wrap your widgets below the 'Description' title into a ListView.

Perhaps there is a rendering overflow, causing the TextFields not to be displayed.

Comment: The whole page is wrapped in a ListView that's why I'm so confused. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you tried to wrap the ListView in an Expanded widget?

Comment: Yes but that didn't work too